# How to make the checkboxes values of grid present in child page to be checked based on inputs of textbox present in parent page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I have a pop up window where I have a grid with checkbox values. Follwoing are the scenario.
1) In parent page on click of Pop Up button,the pop up window should open and I should be able to select the checkbox values.
2) On click of OK Button the values selected should get transffered to the parent page textbox.
3) On click of the pop up button again the values present in textbox should be  checked in the pop up page grid.

Please help me with the 3rd point as I am struggling with this.

Comment: Please share some code to show what you have already tried. It is best to post a [mcve]

Comment: does your program has session? Are you using Javascript pop up?

Comment: var returnValue = window.showModalDialog('../UserControls/PopUpWindow.aspx?q=' + selectCommand + '&d=CommercialReference&t=List of CommercialReferences', objPassData, "location:no;toolbar:no;titlebar:no;resizable:0;status:no;help:no;scrollbars=1");

Comment: This is how I am opening pop Up window where my objPassData contains values which I am passing from parent page.